# Normalize audio in an avi file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, normalization

I have an avi file that has different levels of audio. Is there a way to decrease and increase appropriately where needed the audio of my file using ffmpeg?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you want to normalize... it sounds like you want a compander.

Comment: Ask this question on http://avp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In ffmpeg you can use the volume filter to change the volume of a track. Make sure you download a recent version of the program.

Find out the gain to apply

First you need to analyze the audio stream for the maximum volume to see if normalizing would even pay off:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -af "volumedetect" -f null /dev/null
```

Replace /dev/null with NUL on Windows. This will output something like the following:

```
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7f8ba1c121a0] mean_volume: -16.0 dB
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7f8ba1c121a0] max_volume: -5.0 dB
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7f8ba1c121a0] histogram_0db: 87861
```

As you can see, our maximum volume is -5.0 dB, so we can apply 5 dB gain. If you get a value of 0 dB, then you don't need to normalize the audio.

Apply the volume filter:

Now we apply the volume filter to an audio file. Note that applying the filter means we will have to re-encode the audio stream. What codec you want for audio depends on the original format, of course. Here are some examples:

Plain audio file: Just encode the file with whatever encoder you need:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "volume=5dB" output.mp3
```

Your options are very broad, of course.

AVI format: Usually there's MP3 audio with video that comes in an AVI container:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -af "volume=5dB" -c:v copy -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 output.avi
```

Here we chose quality level 2. Values range from 0–9 and lower means better. Check the MP3 VBR guide for more info on setting the quality. You can also set a fixed bitrate with -b:a 192k, for example.

MP4 format: With an MP4 container, you will typically find AAC audio. We can use ffmpeg's build-in AAC encoder.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -af "volume=5dB" -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k output.mp4
```

Here you can also use other AAC encoders. Some of them support VBR, too. See this answer and the AAC encoding guide for some tips.

In the above examples, the video stream will be copied over using -c:v copy. If there are subtitles in your input file, or multiple video streams, use the option -map 0 before the output filename.

The author's info is: [Jon Skarpeteig](https://superuser.com/users/81491/jon-skarpeteig) in [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/323119/how-can-i-normalize-audio-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: It is much faster to run `ffmpeg -i video.avi -af "volumedetect" -f null /dev/null` with `-vn` as in: `ffmpeg -i video.avi -vn -af "volumedetect" -f null /dev/null` because `-vn` will skip the video stream entirely and just work with the audio.

Answer (score 3):

You can use my [`ffmpeg-normalize`](https://github.com/slhck/ffmpeg-normalize) script for that.

First, install a recent version of ffmpeg. Then, install via `pip install ffmpeg_normalize`, then run it on an AVI file:

```
ffmpeg-normalize input.avi -o output.mkv -c:a aac -b:a 192k
```

Here, we're choosing to re-encode the audio with AAC at 192 kBit/s, and copy the video stream over to the output. This will perform [EBU R128 normalization](https://auphonic.com/blog/2012/08/02/loudness-measurement-and-normalization-ebu-r128-calm-act/), but simple peak/RMS normalization is also possible.